# Avoid chunk / batch processing in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning, large-data

Often I am encountering a pattern of dividing Big processing steps in batches when these steps can't be processed entirely in our Big Data Spark cluster.

For instance, we have a large cross join or some calculus that fails when done with all the input data and then we usually are dividing these spark task in chunks so the spark mini-tasks can complete.

Particularly I doubt this is the right way to do it in Spark.

Is there a recipe to solve this issue? Or even with Spark we are again in the old-way of chunking/batching the work so to the work can be completed in a small cluster?

Is this a mere question of re-partitioning the input data so that Spark can do more sequential processing instead of parallel processing?